# How to get the activity reference from the ComponentName

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the ComponentName of a foreground screen activity. I am able to  get the context object from the same. But I need the activity instance.
How can I get the activity reference from the ComponentName.
All this code will be written in a service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can not get Activity instance from it's component name.You can store Activity instance as static field in a class(when onCreate method of Activity invoked) and get that field in service.

Also what do you want  to do with instance of Activity in a Service?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..                                                              I want that the service should find the activity currently running in the foreground.Also the service should be able to find the views of the current activity. Right now I can get the name of currently running Activity.But I dont know how to get the Activity views. Can U please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need a little more clarity on what your attempting to do, but possibly a:

- `class ActivityWatcher` using the `onActivityStarted` method (or similar)
- to call a class that watches your view Hierarchy
- Watch the parent view and then iterate thru the child views.

This would at least give you all the views from the activities layout that are defined at the time the activity is instantiated.